# How can I check the permissions of a user for an specific element on Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

How can I check if a random user (not the current user, I know only his/her username) has certain permissions on a specific SharePoint list item, list etc.?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

PS: I'm accessing SharePoint by its web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, you should write your own webservice that does a DoesUserhavePermissions check on the specified item for the specified user. Then deploy the webservice to sharepoint...

Comment: This would be so useful... CODEPLEX!

Comment: Is there a CodePlex project that adds the functionality missing from the existing web services? Because there damn well should be!

Answer (score 0):

Can´t you use DoesUserhavePermissions() with the specified token?

Comment: Oh, sry, I forgot to mention that I'm retrieving list items by Sharepoint webservices!